# Что происходит при безусловном переходе при помощи оператора goto?

Tags: c, goto

Собственно, интересует, какие проблемы могут возникнуть при использовании этого оператора.

Для меня очевидно, что `goto` совершенно незаменим во множестве ситуаций:

- построение конечных автоматов;
- выход из глубоко вложенных циклов;
- обработка ошибок и пр.

Поскольку в `C` нет `RAII` и `исключений`, то по сравнению с `C++` диапазон возможных проблем резко сокращается, но проблемы все же остаются.

Например:

```
goto A;
if (a() == 0)
{
    A:;
    b();// Вызов a() пропущен?
}
```

Или:

```
goto A;
// ...
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{   
    A:;
    // i имеет неопределенное значение?
}
```

Или:

```
goto A;
int i;
// ...
i = a();
A:;
i = b();// Определение i пропущено, куда мы записываем результат работы b()?
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос так, чтобы он описывал конкретную проблему с достаточной детализацией для определения адекватного ответа. Вопросы типа "перечислите мне все А и Б" не конструктивны.

Comment: @Kromster поправил вопрос, спасибо за замечание.

Comment: Предположу, в стандарте Си должен быть список (не)определённых поведений на эту тему

Comment: @andreymal, как раз читаю стандарт, но ясности пока нет.

Comment: Спасибо за исправление, но даже с ним, вопрос по прежнему слишком широк.

Comment: По пунктам: 1. Да. 2. Прекрасно заменяется отдельной функцией с return вместо goto. 3. Да, вынужденно.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, я привел очень упрощенный код. Я не совсем понимаю, что происходит, если `goto` переводит выполнение в тело цикла или другого блока. Так же мне не совсем понятно, являются ли переменные, через определение/объявление которых мы перепрыгнули,  доступными для использования.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В языке С время жизни автоматической переменной (кроме VLA) начинается в момент входа в блок, содержащий объявление этой переменной

> - An object whose identifier is declared with no linkage and without the storage-class specifier `static` has *automatic storage duration* [...]
> - For such an object that does not have a variable length array type, its lifetime extends from entry into the block with which it is associated until execution of that block ends in any way [...]

Причем "момент входа в блок" - это чисто *временнАя*, а не *пространственная* характеристика - входить в блок можно любым способом, как через начало, так и прямо в середину. Как только управление попало внутрь блока - все автоматические переменные, объявленные в этом блоке уже существуют, независимо от того, видны ли в месте входа их имена.

```
// Если мы попадаем в блок отсюда...
{ // <- ... то время жизни переменной `b` начинается уже здесь
  ...
  int b; // <- А здесь начинается лишь область видимости имени `b`
  ...
}
```

Таким образом для "создания" переменной (кроме VLA) совсем не обязательно, чтобы управление буквально проходило по определению этой переменной. Переменная уже существует с момента входа в блок.

Поэтому передача управления при помощи `goto` через объявление с инициализацией в С приведет лишь к тому, что переменная не будет инициализирована. Однако на сам факт существования переменной и ее время жизни это не оказывает никакого влияния.

Answer (score 6):

> Вызов a() пропущен?

Да

> i имеет неопределенное значение?

Да

> ```
>     goto A;
>     int i;
> A:  i = b();// Определение i пропущено, куда мы записываем результат работы
> ```

Не зависимо от местоположения определения, время жизни обычной переменной — целый блок. Также не важно, как произошёл вход в блок — в процессе обычного исполнения или через `goto` — компилятор должен обеспечить место хранения для данного объекта.

> Я не совсем понимаю, что происходит, если goto переводит выполнение в тело цикла или другого блока.

На уровне языка это не важно. Можно, пожалуй руководствоваться сентенцией: выделять ресурсы под объекты с автоматическим временем жизни — забота компилятора, а инициализировать их — программиста.

> Так же мне не совсем понятно, являются ли переменные, через определение/объявление которых мы перепрыгнули, доступными для использования.

Да, являются; единственное, что явно запрещено — это пересекать объявление массива переменной длины в его же области видимости:

```
size_t n=getSize();
if (n<=0) { goto A; }       // ошибка
else if (n==1) { goto B; } // ок
{
  int a[n];
  A: a[n-2] = doSomething();
}
B:;
```

Также, строго говоря, когда управление проходит через объявление, значение переменной становится неопределённым:

```
        int j=0;
        goto assign;
start:  int i;
        j = foo(i); // здесь значение i, строго говоря, не определено.
assign: i=-1;
        if (j==0) {goto start;}
```

В остальном возможно практически всё, а семантика «так как оно и выглядит». Скользких мест, на вскидку, нет.

Comment: "На самом деле, с точки зрения стандарта такого понятия, как «определение переменной» просто нет,..." - это, конечно, неправда.

Comment: @AnT, специально просмотрел — в отношении объектов используется исключительно термины «declarator» и «declaration», а «definition» применяется только к функциям, типам и макросам...

Comment: Это как это O_o??? **6.9 External definitions**: "An external definition is an external declaration that is also a definition of a function (other than an inline definition) or an **object**.". Далее **6.9.2 External object definitions**

Comment: @AnT, в ответе по этому поводу оговорился: «исключение — разве что глобальные переменные со внешней линковкой»

Comment: И? Перечисленные мною темы ясно говорят, что `static int i;` на уровне файла - это внешнее *определение*. Но оно не является "глобальной переменной с внешней линковкой".

Comment: Также "6.7 Declarations" ясно говорит: "A definition
of an identifier is a declaration for that identifier that: — for an object, causes storage to be reserved for that object;". Выделением памяти для любой переменной в С занимается именно definition. Никаких исключений из этого правила для локальных переменных не сделано. Уже этого достаточно, чтобы закрыть тему.

Comment: @AnT, ладно, уговорил — был не прав... поправил ответ...

Comment: Не совсем понял последний пример, объясните, пожалуйста, подробнее.

Comment: @MGNeo, это так... пример высосанный из пальца... сначала выполняется переход на `assign` и якобы устанавливается значение `i`, но затем после перехода на `start` значение `i`, строго говоря, снова не определено... т.е. после прохождения через объявление без инициализатора, вообще говоря, значение переменной не определено.

Comment: Последний пример, я уверен, неверен. Значение переменной полностью определено и равно `-1`. "после прохождения через объявление без инициализатора, вообще говоря, значение переменной не определено" - такого можно было бы ожидать от С++ ( и то я не уверен для типа int), но в С здесь все с порядке.

Comment: @AnT, C99, 6.2.4/6 `... If an initialization is specified for the object, it is performed each time the declaration is reached in the execution of the block; otherwise, the value becomes indeterminate each time the declaration is reached.` ... я и сам удивился...

Comment: Да, хорошая цитата. Я помню, что где-то читал что-то подобное, но списал это на С++. А оказывается оно прямо в стандарте С присутствует. Тогда все верно. Значение `i` не определено.

Answer (score 2):

Весь скомпилированный код испещрён **goto**. Как всё это выглядит в скомпилированном коде:

```
/*
goto A;
if (a() == 0){
    A:;
    b();// Вызов a() пропущен?
  }
*/
goto A;
  ax:= call a();
  if ax == 0 goto A ; 
  else goto Next ; 
A:;
  call b();
Next:;
```

Для команды **if** вы привыкли, что некоторые участки кода НЕ выполняются, а тут вдруг пропущенный вызов `a()` у вас производит страх.

```
/*
goto A;
// ...
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {   
    A:;
    // i имеет неопределенное значение?
}
*/
goto A;
  стек[-4] := 0 ;
ForBody:;
  if стек[-4] < 10 goto A;
  else goto Next;
A:;
  ++ стек[-4];
  goto ForBody;
Next:;
```

Здесь переменная не инициализирована, эта лажа уже на совести программиста. Будет неопределённое поведение. Но иногда, значение переменных не влияют на ход алгоритма, поэтому на совести программера будет: это фишка алгоритма или баг.

```
/*goto A;
int i;
// ...
i = a();
A:;
i = b();// Определение i пропущено, куда мы записываем результат работы b()?
*/
    goto A;
    stack[-4] := call a();
A:;    
    stack[-4] := call b();
```

Значение переменной **i** хранится в стеке, и место уже выделено при старте функции заранее. Так-что фактическое исполнение программы желательно знать. Это очень помогает разобраться как работает комп.

Answer (score 0):

Любую программу с `goto` можно эквивалентными преобразованиями превратить в программу без `goto`, и тогда поддерживать ее встанет намного проще.

Когда я вижу в чужом коде метку, я очень сильно настораживаюсь - а вдруг на эту метку прыгают из кода, который находится в другом файле, который прицеплен сюда при помощи `#include`?

Количество WTF в секунду катастрофически возрастает, что в нашей работе и так неприемлемо.

Решение - почитайте [программную статью](http://%D0%A1%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%8E%20%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%20-%20%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%20%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8B,%20%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D1%83%D1%88%D0%BB%D0%B0.) Дейкстры и ее критику.

> Для меня очевидно, что `goto` совершенно незаменим во множестве
>   ситуаций:
>
> - построение конечных автоматов;
> - выход из глубоко вложенных циклов;
> - обработка ошибок и пр.

Очевидно как раз обратное:

- Использовать процедуры или классы с полиморфизмом - не нужен goto
- return/throw
- return/throw, RAII

Comment: Вопрос по Си, а не крестам... и страхи беспочвены т.к. в стандартных версиях языков `goto` выполняет переход только в рамках одной функции.

Comment: Каждый точит так как хочет - желаю вам не сталкиваться с тем кодом, который написан такими вот бесстрашными разработчиками.

Comment: Ну, во-первых, Дейкстра чистый теоретик, и его идеи с реальной жизнью коррелируют весьма слабо. Во-вторых, эта статья лохматых годов давно потеряла актуальность. Она появилась когда чуть ли не большая часть кода писалась на Фортране IV, и проблема goto действительно стояла очень остро. Те времена давно прошли. Хотя goto и сейчас полезен для выхода из вложенных циклов, реально он используется настолько редко, что проблемы с ним просто не существует. Сейчас появилась масса новых способов сделать из программы кашу, так что хватит уже мучить бедный старый goto, пусть живет.

Comment: [Structured Programming with go to Statements
DONALD E. KNUTH](http://www.kohala.com/start/papers.others/knuth.dec74.html)  / Не помню, оттуда ли известное высказывание  --  *`"структурность программы определяется наличием структуры, а не отсутствием оператора goto"`* / И хотя,  всегда можно уйти от goto, но иногда (а в самом деле на практике  редко) goto все же реально улучшает восприятие кода

Comment: В теории, конечно, любой код с `goto` можно заменить на эквивалентный код без `goto`, но в некоторых случаях это нерационально. Например, выход из множества вложенных циклов или реализация блока `finally`.

Comment: @MGNeo - Если вложено больше двух циклов, код уже должен идти на вторчермет по причине облапшения.